# How to generate controllers within Rails 3.1 engines

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have generated a Rails 3.1 engine using the following command:

```
rails plugin new forum --full
```

I then copied the plugin to an existing rails app. Now when I run the following command, it is generating the controller inside the rails app, not within the plugin directory.

```
cd vendor/gems/forum
rails g controller Users
```

I tried running the command from the Rails root directory, still the same issue.

Kindly help me!

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you are editing the Rails Engine within the the Main Application. You can do this, but the idea of Rails Engine is that the Engine is a gem that is listed in the Gemfile and installed via bundler.

If you want to add a controller to a Rails Engine,

```
rails plugin new blorgh --full
cd blorgh
bundle exec rails g controller Users
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But still the same issue.